# MYSQL Insert Data into table using Foreign Keys from different tables

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have a temporary table "teststepdump" created by "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE". The temporary table contains the Data of different tables connected by foreign keys together in the table TestResult:

1. teststepdump (dummyno, stationno, name, result)
2. duttest (ID, DUTID, processTime)
3. dut (ID, DummyNr)
4. station (ID, stationno)
5. teststepname(ID, name)
6. teststepresult(DUTTestID,TeststepID,Result)

I´m trying this way using a stored procedure, but I get Error 1452:

> SQL Fehler (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails  (`database`.`teststepresult`, CONSTRAINT
>   `teststepresult_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DUTTestID`) REFERENCES `duttest`
>   (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
BEGIN
DECLARE dt_id INT;
SELECT teststepresult.DUTTestID INTO dt_id FROM teststepresult
INNER JOIN duttest ON teststepresult.DUTTestID = duttest.ID
INNER JOIN dut ON duttest.DUTID = dut.ID
INNER JOIN station ON duttest.StationID = station.Nummer
INNER JOIN teststepdump ON teststepresult.ID = teststepdump.ID
WHERE
dut.DummyNr = teststepdump.dummyno AND
station.Nummer = teststepdump.stationno;

INSERT INTO teststepresult (DUTTestID, TeststepID, Result) 
SELECT dt_id, teststepname.ID, teststepdump.Result 
FROM teststepdump
INNER JOIN teststepname ON teststepdump.name = teststepname.name
WHERE 
teststepname.name = teststepdump.name;
terminate teststepdump;
END
```

For a single INSERT this stored Procedure is working for me, but I want to avoid a "for" Loop;:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE t_id INT;
DECLARE tn_id INT;

SELECT teststepname.ID INTO tn_id FROM teststepname 
WHERE  teststepname.Name = name;

SELECT duttest.ID INTO t_id FROM duttest
INNER JOIN dut ON duttest.DUTID = dut.ID 
INNER JOIN station ON duttest.stationID = station.ID
WHERE
dut.DummyNr = dummyno AND 
station.Nummer = stationno;

IF NOT t_id IS NULL AND NOT tn_id IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO teststepresult (DUTTestID, TeststepID, Result) 
VALUES (t_id, tn_id, Result);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of table `teststepdump`? (I mean the creation sql code)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `teststepdump` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dummyno` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `stationno` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',`Result` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)

Comment: it seems doesn't have foreign key... can you show the structure of `teststepresult` ?

Comment: Yes teststepdump has no foreign key.

Comment: what about `teststepresult` ?

Answer (score 1):

I Solved the Problem !

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO teststepresult (DUTTestID, StepName, Result) 
SELECT duttest.DUTID, teststepdump.name, teststepdump.Result 
FROM duttest
INNER JOIN dut ON duttest.DUTID = dut.ID
INNER JOIN station ON duttest.StationID = station.ID
INNER JOIN teststepdump ON dut.DummyNr = teststepdump.dummyno
WHERE 
dut.DummyNr = teststepdump.dummyno AND
station.Nummer = teststepdump.stationno;
#truncate teststepdump; 
END
```